# ExtJS grid filtering - activating two at the same time

Tags: extjs, grid, filtering

I have the following code to filter a grid from values inputed in a form on a click of a button. The problem is that the first time the filters are activated, only the first filter (displayNameFilter) will be included in the request.

The second time and on, both filters will be included in a request. How can I work around that issue?

```
var nameFilter = grid.filters.getFilter('name');

if (!nameFilter) {
    nameFilter = grid.filters
            .addFilter({
                type : 'string',
                dataIndex : 'name'
            });
}
nameFilter.setValue(Ext.getCmp('name-filter').getValue());

var displayNameFilter = grid.filters.getFilter('displayName');

if (!displayNameFilter) {
    displayNameFilter = grid.filters
            .addFilter({
                type : 'string',
                dataIndex : 'displayName'
            });
}

displayNameFilter.setValue(Ext.getCmp('display-name-filter').getValue());

displayNameFilter.setActive(true, false);
nameFilter.setActive(true, false);
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, do you know what is actually causing this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
handler : function() {

    var filters = [];

    // get filters from a form...
    var values = filterForm.getValues();
    for (var f in values) {
        var value = values[f];
        if (value) {
            filters.push({ property: f, value: value });
        }
    }

    //...and add all of them to the store used by the grid directly
    if (filters.length) {
        // prevent events firing here...
        gridStore.clearFilter(true);
        // ...because they will fire here
        gridStore.filter(filters);
    } else {
        gridStore.clearFilter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. The solution is a bit hokey but it works for me, notice that the filter variable is defined a second time within the defer call (it is needed):

```
grid.filters.createFilters();
var nameFilter = grid.filters.getFilter('name');
if (!nameFilter) {
    nameFilter = grid.filters
            .addFilter({
                type : 'string',
                dataIndex : 'name'
            });
}
nameFilter.setActive(true);
var displayNameFilter = grid.filters.getFilter('displayName');
if (!displayNameFilter) {
    displayNameFilter = grid.filters
            .addFilter({
                type : 'string',
                dataIndex : 'displayName'
            });
}
displayNameFilter.setActive(true);
Ext.Function.defer(function() {
    nameFilter = grid.filters.getFilter('name');
    nameFilter.setValue(Ext.getCmp('name-filter').getValue());
    displayNameFilter = grid.filters.getFilter('displayName');
    displayNameFilter.setValue(Ext.getCmp('display-name-filter').getValue());
}, 10);
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. The `nameFilter` is called first and the `displayNameFilter` is skipped in the first pass anyway. The second pass works.

Comment: if you don't add `grid.filters.createFilters();` it cannot find filter defined before. thanks, works well... but, I cant figure out what does the Defer do here? I am using `filter.setValue(value);` then `filter.setActive(true);` then it works...